# how to escape operators in JSP expressions

Tags: java, html, jsp, escaping

I am embedding Java code in a piece of JSP on a HTML page:

```
<c:when test="<%=\"F\".equals(result[1])||\"P\".equals(result[1])%>">
```

The above code works. Now I need to make `"F".equals(result[1])` to `!("F".equals(result[1]))`. How do I do that?

Comment: Are your running this as html or as a jsp in an application server?  Your tags and explanation are confusing.

Comment: html does not get processed by the JVM so you are out of luck.  You need to create a proper J2EE app with servlets to make this work.

Comment: thx tom, i'm trying it out as a j2ee app on weblogic server now. my main peeve is with the syntax and the need to escape

Comment: When using jsp syntax you should not need scriptlets.  The jsp syntax knows about your beans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to use scriptlet expressions inside JSTL tag attributes. You should use the JSP EL instead:

```
<c:when test="${result[1] == 'F' or result[1] == 'P'}>...</c:when>
```

Read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info for information and links about the JSTL and the EL.